# Make shortcut for navigational functions

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, shortcuts, numpad

Is there anyway to create shortcuts for functions like <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Pg Up</kbd>, <kbd>Pg Down</kbd>, etc? I frequently use the aforementioned keys, however those keys are only available when the numpad is disabled - there is no dedicated keys for those function on my laptop. I was thinking of using the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to trigger them even when the numpad is enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Approach 1. Using <kbd>Fn</kbd> key

1. Check the keycode of yours key. Run this program at terminal.

   ```
   xev
   ```

   [image]

   At this example, the terminal shows that the keycode for my <kbd>k</kbd> is "45".
2. Change them as you like creating this file:

   ```
   gedit ~/.Xmodmap
   ```

   It's contents should look like this example:

   ```
   keycode 180 = Home End Down
   ```

   (`keycode 180` is for <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> at my notebook)

   Ilustration:

   [image]

   (Obs.: if I want to change my <kbd>k</kbd> I must use `keycode 45` as showed at step "1", if I want to change my <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> I must use `keycode 180`).
3. Log out and log back in or reboot or run this:

   ```
   xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
   ```

### Approach 2. Using a shortcut (combination keys)

1. [Install xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool)

   ```
   sudo aptitude install xdotool
   ```
2. Open Gnome Keybindings

   ```
   gnome-keybinding-properties
   ```
3. Create the shortcut with this commands:

   ```
   xdotool getactivewindow key Home
   xdotool getactivewindow key End
   xdotool getactivewindow key Page_Up
   xdotool getactivewindow key Page_Down
   ```

   Example:

   [image]

Enjoy!

Comment: Running `xev` opens a white window with a square outline. What next?

Comment: Ah, I didn't think Terminal output was important... Can you please give me a random example making <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>random key</kbd> reproducing effects of pressing Home button?

Comment: I don't understand what I should write in the new file. What does each word after `keycode 51 =` represent?

Comment: OH! So `keycode 51` is called by the keys that's mentioned?

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't get what I have to do. For example, my Home button's `keycode 79`, and I want to use Home with Fn + Numpad 7 key. Due to circumstances, I am not able to use Ubuntu as much as I'd like to, so sorry for the drawn out discussion.

Comment: But I still don't understand what the example in the screen shot does.

Comment: This example make my physical keyboard key that has this "]" simbol when I look down at my keyboard  (witch is represented by keycode 51 when I look to my monitor, at terminal output of xev) to function like if I had pushed Sysreq key if I pushed it alone. If I push it with Shift, then it will insert this character "]". If I push it with Alt, then it will insert this character "}". If I push it with right Alt, it will insert this character "a". And finally, if I push it with Shift and right Alt together, it will insert this character "A".

Comment: I understand now. But each of the keys you specified were automatically assigned to shift, alt, etc in the order they were written. But what about the Fn key, and how do I only assign a function with Fn?

Comment: Like I said before: not all keys can be combined with "Fn". The keys that can are those witch different keycode numbers when pressed alone or combined with "Fn". Check this with xev.

Comment: `xwv` does not recognise Fn being pressed individually, and pressing with numpad 7 (where I want to apply Home function) does not give a new keycode. So combining with Fn out of question? What about the super key?

Comment: I think that with Super key it's possible, but it's a totally different question. I will see if I can do that when I get home in a few hours ;-)

Comment: @desgua, you don't how much of a help you are! Thanks!

Comment: It's done. Look at the answer ;-)

Comment: Oh man, I gotta install something... So how does this work. Say I want to use End by Fn+L? Does this support Fn?

Comment: Nope. As I said before, this is another approach for a different question. It is simple to install. Just click at 'Install xdotool' and you're done.

Comment: I know installing is simple, but I want to use as less packages as possible. What does it support? I can't understand from the example what key you're assigning what function.

Comment: The function is Home and the combination shortcut isn't showed in this picture. I think you should try to follow the explanation instead of just read because many things are intuitive.

Comment: Where can I get the list of keys it supports? It isn't there in man.

Comment: You can just open the Gnome keybindings and try the keys you want.

Comment: For the .Xmodmap solution, the functions, how do I skip to assigning something with Alt without starting with Shift and all?

Comment: I didn't understand what you are asking now.

Comment: In the example screen shot, each of the buttons defined for nothing, right shift, left shift, etc. I am assuming that in the order of the functions written, it's assigned to nothing, Shift, Alt, rAlt, etc. So how can I move to Alt without assigning anything for shift?

Comment: I still don't get it. What screenshot (let's call then 1 -> http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/xev.png --- 2 -> http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/Xmodmap.1.png --- 3 -> http://i.imgur.com/gwnV5.jpg ? I can't find this assigns you pointed "nothing, Shift, Alt, rAlt, etc."

Comment: For the image 2, you had said: 'This example make my physical keyboard key that has this "]" simbol when I look down at my keyboard (witch is represented by keycode 51 when I look to my monitor, at terminal output of xev) to function like if I had pushed Sysreq key if I pushed it alone. If I push it with Shift, then it will insert this character "]". If I push it with Alt, then it will insert this character "}". If I push it with right Alt, it will insert this character "a". And finally, if I push it with Shift and right Alt together, it will insert this character "A".'

Comment: Now I got it. You just need to put "NoSymbol" (without cotes) to move to the next assignment.

Comment: What all keys are available to combine? Is there some sort of `man` page I can refer to?

Comment: You can test the keys you want opening `gnome-keybinding-properties` > go to a shortcut named `Disabled` > click on it > test your key combination. Also you can read `man xev` and `man xmodmap`